# Kernel Configuration, Which Processor family?

Tags: central-processing-unit, kernel

Which processor family should I use for the cpu shown below for the best fit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the model name field it tells you there that it's an Intel i5 CPU. Given the choices you have available from your screenshot I'd go with "Core 2/newer Xeon".

See this wikipedia article for more info about ["Intel Core" architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core).

---

If you look at the output from `lscpu` in [@tdk2fe's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/497845/2518) it shows the following info about their particular CPU:

- family 6
- model # 37

You can look these up on the Intel website. If you google "cpu family 6 model 37" the first link tells you it's a [Clarkdale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkdale_%28microprocessor%29)

Comment: TY very much, that is what i picked and what i was thinking from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely an Intel x86 family.  Run `lscpu` and it will give you more specific information.

#### sample output

```
% lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1199.000
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

You man need to install a package (.deb/.rpm) depending on your distro to install `lscpu`. On Fedora/CentOS distros it's part of the RPM package **util-linux-ng**.

Comment: OP's screenshot shows it's an i5, cpu family 6 -- how does this, or `lscpu`, help them choose an option in their `make xconfig`?

Comment: http://oi50.tinypic.com/2sb5uhe.jpg    But it still doesn't really help me know what one to pick : /

Comment: It actually does if you understand what it's telling you, it shows that the CPU is family 6, model # 37. You can look these up on the Intel website. If you google "cpu family 6 model 37" the first link tells you it's a [Clarkdale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkdale_(microprocessor))